# android build system get the source code path base on package name

Tags: android, android-source

I want to get package source code base on package name, eg `xxx.apk`

I know it could filter by grep `LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME`. but the AOSP source was too large.

Is it any build system command could list all package name and path?

Regards

Comment: `grep` can be very slow on AOSP because it will search through all files by default and not just source code. I would recommend `ag` (aka silver_searcher), which is advertised as grep with better defaults. It can go through the AOSP code much faster. For reference, on my system doing `ag LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME` over the entire AOSP tree takes < 10s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**

```sh
. build/envsetup.sh

# Show list of modules for the selected configuration.
lunch
m modules

# Grep for your module.
mgrep <module>
```

**Explanation**

After calling `. build/envsetup.sh` you can use `mgrep` to only grep build configuration files.

Be aware, that Android currently uses two build configuration types in parallel. The old makefile type files (`Android.mk`) will contain `LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME`. However, the new Soong module files (`Android.bp`) have a different syntax. You better grep for the module name and not for `LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME`.

You can use `m modules` to get a list of all modules known to the build system. This command requires you to run `lunch` first. Also the list returned by `m modules` will only contain the modules that are selected by the `lunch` configuration.